# How to deal with questions that change

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, we give a correct answer to a question, and then later, the OP changes the question, so that the answer does not match the question any more. Later, some careless readers come in and vote down those answers that used to be correct but do not match the question any more because the question was edited.

We cannot keep "polling" all the questions that we have ever answered to see if they are changed, so what is the best way to deal with these stupid down-votes?

Comment: In this situation, the OP is more stupid than a downvoter :)

Comment: Usually a question is changed in the first hour after posting and that's it.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby That question is about OP leaving comments requesting follow up. In that case there is little concern about the answer being downvoted by late visitors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not the down votes that are stupid; the question being changed is the problem.

In such a case, one thing should happen: the question needs to be reverted, if it was truly altered significantly.

If you can't or don't want to do it, or if you already have and the OP edits it back, flag the question as "Other" and describe the problem. We'll take care of it.

Answer (score 7):

When a user edits his question so that the current answers no longer makes any sense, you should usually just revert the change and ask them to post a new question instead.

If they re-do the same edit or make trouble, flag for a mod.